# Background animation within non-rectangular, Canvas or SVG shape?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, canvas, svg

The goal is to add a dynamic, animated background (JavaScript or CSS) to a non-rectangular, Canvas or SVG shape.

Here's an example animation: https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/NPMGjE

**[Here's the shape, along with a mock-up of the end-goal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dwx3.png)**

If this was a standard web page, then a layered div or shape could be used.  Unfortunately, this is an l-band section displayed on a "Smart TV" -- so the white area (in the example image) must be transparent in order for the RF video to be view-able.

Whether it's a Canvas or SVG shape, clipping can be used to layer and mask shapes -- but, (from everything I've tried) clipping doesn't work on anything applied directly to a *class* or *id*.

So far, I haven't been able to locate any examples of this being done.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Example Code using basic clipping ...

```
(function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('lband');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    setCanvasSize();
    draw();
})();


function setCanvasSize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    W   = canvas.width;
    H   = canvas.height;
    Hl  = canvas.height * .85;
    Wl  = canvas.width  * .85;

    draw();
}


function draw() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, Hl);
    ctx.lineTo(Wl, Hl);
    ctx.lineTo(Wl, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(W, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(W, H);
    ctx.lineTo(0, H);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.clip();
    // Draw red rectangle after clip()
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: I've got no clue what you're talking about, going through you history it seems you're building things for a LG smart TV. My knowledge is very limited in that regard, that said, you can clear parts of the canvas in order to make it transparent, (atleast on the web)  ala `$.clearRect(0, 0, 360, 360);`  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXpyvZ

Comment: Well damn Lars.  For not having a clue what I'm talking about, you sure gave a great answer.  It looks like `$.clearRect` has really good browser support as well. Can't believe I never knew about this.  Thank you sir. :)  I'll give it a shot.  If you'd like to submit your comment as an Answer, I'd be honored to accept it as the approved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Smart Tv apps scene. However, on ye olde regular web, you can restore transparency on (parts of) a canvas by calling `clearRect(xCord, yCord, xLength, yLenght)` on the drawing context.
This [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXpyvZ) has set a `background-image` on the `<body>`, you'll see that the image is revealed when calling `clearRect`. I suspect your Tv will act the same.

If it's required that you do not have any elements occupying the video space, there might be another solution inside pandora's box.
You could try to use 2 canvases, one for left side, one for the bottom, and draw on them simultaneously, giving the illusion of being connected.
 ( as in, it's one L-shaped canvas.)